# Undefined reference to method of partially specialized class

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, partial-specialization

I've been working on a set of template classes that represent various bits of geometry, and I realized that I would like to be able to specialize various classes to handle references and pointers e.g.

```
template<typename T>
class rect{ // as in rectangle
public:
  point<T> point1, point2; // Point simply contains two instances of type T
  ...    // Twenty functions or so follow
};

template<typename T>
class rect<point<T>>{ // trying to put a point in a point makes no sense anyway
public:               // so I see this technique as valid
  point<T>& point1,& point2;
  ...    // I really don't want to redefine them if I don't have to
};
```

The problems start with my test program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <TGeometry.hpp>

template<typename T>
class test{
public:
  T A;

  void myfunc(){std::cout << "from base\n";}
  void otherfunc(T O);
  test(const T nA) : A(nA) {}
  test(){}
};

template<typename T>
void test<T>::otherfunc(T O){A += O;}

template<typename T>
class test<T&>{
public:
  T& A;

  void myfunc(){std::cout << "from refr\n";}
  void otherfunc(T O); // Shouldn't this default to using test<T>::otherfunc?
  test(T& nA) : A(nA) {}
};


int main(){ using std::cout;
  using namespace d2;

  test<int> Atest(5);
  test<int&> Btest(Atest.A);

  Atest.myfunc(), Btest.myfunc();
  Btest.otherfunc(Atest.A); // test<T&>::otherfunc undefined?
  Atest.otherfunc(10);

  std::cin.ignore();
  return 0;
}
```

This program compiled in Mingw_w64, exits with

```
C:\Users\*>g++ -o test.exe quicktest.cpp -I .\Libraries
C:\Users\THEMAG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccszH6xM.o:quicktest.cpp:(.text+0x42):undefined reference to `A<char, 2>::f()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This may just be a lack of knowledge on my part, but [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) website (at the bottom, first example under members of partial specializations) implies that you can exclude the function definition for a partial specialization, as long as you have declared it, and it will default to using the primary template's definition.

Being able to do this would save me days of work, as I wouldn't have to redefine all of my class's functions. So my question is, what is keeping my code from compiling, and can/how can I specialize my classes for references(I'll still need to do it for pointers) without having to redefine their functions? Is this simply an issue of references changing how the code would have to work, e.g. the primary specialization's function would just shift the reference if it's function was used.

Comment: The error message can't possibly be related to the code you show. The code doesn't mention a template named `A`, nor a member function named `f`.

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted the linker error your code generates, since there is no reference to `f()` in the code sample you posted.

Comment: According to ideone (http://ideone.com/JZemgY) the error in your MVCE is `undefined reference to 'test<int&>::otherfunc(int)'`?

Comment: `Shouldn't this default to using test<T>::otherfunc?` No it should not. Class template specialization is largely separate and independent from its primary template; it doesn't have to resemble the primary in any way. It can have a completely different set of members, say. If you want the two to have something in common, use the normal OO design mechanisms to achieve that - e.g. have them derive from a common base class, or delegate to a common helper.

Comment: Also, for your stated goal, if you have C++11/C++14 you should look into `std::remove_reference`, `std::decay` and `std::enable_if`.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference

Comment: Oh wait. I just didn't read the commenting in that website's code. Should I remove this question or leave it as a warning as to the dangers of not reading everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this notion in which specialized class templates inherit the implementations of methods from the unspecialized class template is correct. Consider for example std::enable_if. The entire point of this class is to trigger subsitution failure by referencing a type that doesn't exist in a specialized version of the template. If the behavior you described were correct, then this wouldn't work. Or at least, you would need to define enable_if using two specializations instead of a generic and one specialization (which is not the case).

I think this is an "XY" situation: you'd like to be able to do something, but I think more likely you should revise your design so you don't need to do that thing. I can imagine situations where getting the generic template member function would be useful, but it should be relatively rare, and this doesn't strike me as one of those cases.

More likely, if the whole point of your template is to put type T in a point, and putting a point in a point makes no sense, you should just static assert that T is not itself some kind of Point template class. What extra functionality does the specialization give you? Why do you want need a reference/pointer specialization?

Comment: It turns out that my interpretation of the website was lacking. It specifically says in the commenting on their code that the function has to be defined, but I guess I was in too much of a hurry to get through it all.

The idea behind having rect<point<T>> or triangle<point<T>> create a class with references to point<T> is so I can have objects like triangles connect to form a mesh, and use a single point to represent each vertex

Comment: It's not generally a good idea to store references to external entities in an object, you can get dangling references very easily. Honestly, I would probably forego templates entirely and just use a rect that stores Point<double>, unless you really anticipate using something other than doubles. Don't pay for complexity you don't need.